# Has Mathematics Stack Exchange changed its font size?

Tags: discussion, font, layout

Has Mathematics SE made its font bigger? Everything seems so big now. Is it just for me or has Mathematics SE actually implemented it? Please confirm. I'm also attaching some pictures of it.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

These texts appear bigger than the usual ones I used to see.

**Edit**

The problem is fixed on my end. Thanks M.SE.

Comment: Same here. It’s too big!

Comment: I really don't like this big font. Seems like someone is shouting at me.

Comment: It's too big only in mobile. On the desktop it remains the same comfortable size.

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange: [Mobile font-size way too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large)

Comment: @lhf it is fixed now

Comment: @XanderHenderson no it is not fixed in SE sites...it's only fixed on meta

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I did not claim it was fixed.  I linked to a meta report of the same problem.

Comment: It seems CV and Maths are yet to be fixed.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods yes you're right

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry for the jumbo font size on smaller viewports. A fix has been deployed, but it may take to reflect on all Stack Exchange sites. Expect to be resolved for you tomorrow at the latest.

Quoting [my response on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391582/163535):

> **tl;dr**: This bug has been [patched in our design system](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v1.10.1) and the update has been shipped to production.
>
> ---
>
> […]
>
> This was due to a change to some `font-size` values to replace explicit pixel values with calculated values based on custom properties. To be honest, I'm not sure why the calculated values cause this issue and explicit pixel values don't. Nevertheless, changing back to explicit pixel values resolves the issue.

Comment: I encounter the problem on math SE but not on math meta SE. I have also seen the patch (on github) which you have linked here. Is there anyway to verify (via "view source" in browser) whether this fix has reached at my end via cdn?

Comment: The problem is now fixed at my end.